# Lenovo Yoga S740 booting Ubuntu installation media black screen

Tags: live-usb

I'm having problems booting ubuntu 19.10 installation media on the lenovo yoga S740. 
Some info: The device features the new ice lake i7-1065G7 and a dedicated Nvidia MX250 and its the uhd version.
I created a install usb stick, disabled secure boot in the bios, checked that storage mode is set to ahci.
Selecting the usb stick showed grub but choosing try Ubuntu only shows a blank black screen with fans running.
Increasing the screen brightness via fn shortcuts didn't help, safe graphics option neither and the typical grub boot parameters like nomodeset and noapic/nolapic.

I read a post that the xps 13 7390 with the same new cpu works flawlessly with 19.10 that's why I tried the newest Ubuntu with the 5.3.0 kernel.

Comment: The hardware being so new, I doubt support is very good.

Comment: Yeah I guess so too, thanks. Do you think support will come eventually or is it possible to be a permanent incompatibility?

Comment: I just bought the same one and I'm experienced same problem. I achieved installing 19.10 version via 18.04 and distro upgrades. 18.04 can be installed quite well (with secure boot enabled), but lacks support for wi-fi and thunderbolt, which works only in kernels 5.1.x and above. Current problems I have in 19.10 are sometimes boots to grub command line and suspend doesn't work well. After some more tryouts, I will create a question here and post a link to it for you.

Comment: Since asking the question I achieved pretty great success. I managed to install PopOS 19.10 on the device. Most things work well except typical things like power saving mode or triple display extension (don't know about TB3). I had to use the Fedora Media creation tool to create an USB stick with pop os 19.10 with the proprietary Nvidia drivers included, turn off secure boot and install it. Wish you luck

Comment: Created the [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1187534/514712) as promised.

Comment: PopOS is not an appropriate solution for me. I will stick to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "modprobe.blacklist=nouveau". I still had to do it with MX150 and GTX1060 laptops with 19.04. I think nouveau does not play well with optimus.

If you manage to install, booting from HDD will also need it until you install NV drivers (which will put a file doing the same thing in /etc/modprobe.d).

Comment: Will try that soon. Hopefully it works since nouveau.modeset=0 did not work